# XMLHttpRequest not sent

Tags: javascript, ajax

We are three developers working on a web-app project with Django.

Some communications client-server use an API. One particular request is not sending on one of the developer's computer. We use the same Browser (Firefox quantum 64.0 (64 bits)), same OS (Ubuntu 18.04).

Here is the JS snippet:

```
function requestHandler(url){
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', getCookie('csrftoken'));

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            drawLogTable();
        }
        else if (this.readyState == 4){
            console.log(this);
            new PNotify({
                title: 'Échec!',
                text: "Opération impossible: " + this.statusText,
                type: 'error'
            });
        }
    }
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Note that `url` is `'../../api/log?action=accept&id=1'`

On all the working computers and browsers, the request posts and does a 404 since server-side has no implementation yet. On the non-working computer, chromium works, but under Firefox, the request is not even sent (server log is empty) and the request object is completely empty (no status, no text).

We have other AJAX requests in the same type that are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
 xhttp.onload = function(){
        if (this.status == 200) {
            drawLogTable();
}
```